# Performance improvement for GZ to ORC File

Tags: hive, azure-hdinsight

Please let me know Is there any faster way to move (*.gz) to ORC table directly.

1)Another thought, from *.gz file to NON Partition table, Rather than creating External Table and dumping gz file data to External Table. Is there any other approach for quicker loading from Gz to External Table. We are thinking of 2 other approaches like Can we have ADF with Custom .exe to uncompress  *.gz file and upload to Azure Blob.

For Example : If the *.Gz File is 10 GB and Un Compressed File is 120 GB , time it takes to uncompress is  40 Mins, How do we upload this un compressed 120 GB data File to Azure Blob. Do we need to have Azure Blob SDK for uploading or Will ADF Executes .exe at location where data is present i.e. exactly at the cluster which holds Blob Data. ( If ADF executes .exe at Azure Blob Storage Data Center’s Cluster, then there will be no Network cost, No Network latency and upload time to upload Uncompressed data will be very less). So Is it possible with ADF?. Will it be right approach ?

3. If above approach doesn’t work, If we create MR Solution where Mapper is going to UnCompress Gz File and Uploads to Azure Blob Storage, will there be any performance improvement, since I just need to create External Table pointing to uncompressed File. MR will be executing at Azure Blob storage location.
4. We see ORC and ORC with Partition are performing at same (sometimes we see minimal difference b/w ORC partition and ORC without partition). Will ORC With Partition perform better than ORC . Will ORC With Partition Bucketing performs better than ORC Partition ?.  I see each ORC Partition File is close 50-100 MB and ORC With Out Partition (each File size 30-50 MB).

**Note: 120 GB of Un Compressed Data is compressed to 17 GB of ORC File Format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that I know to move from gz to ORC file format is by writing a Hive query. Using a compressed format will always be slower since it needs to be decompressed before conversion. You may want to play around with these parameters as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920328/how-to-improve-performance-of-loading-data-from-non-partition-table-into-orc-par), to see if it speed up moving from gz to orc.

For question #1 above, you may want to follow up with Azure Data Factory team.

For question #3, I have not tried it but computing on uncompressed data should be faster than using compressed data.

For #4, depends on what the field you are partitioning on. Make sure your key is not under partitioned (i.e. results in too few partitions). Also ensure you add sorted by to add a secondary partitioning key. Refer to [this](https://streever.atlassian.net/wiki/display/HADOOP/Optimizing+ORC+Files+for+Query+Performance) link for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Hive has native support for compressed format, including GZIP, BZIP2 and deflate. So you can upload .gz files to Azure Blob and create external table with those files directly. And then you can create table with ORC and load the data there. Normally Hive runs faster with compressed files, please refer to [Compression in Hadoop by MSIT](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/C/6/1C66D134-1FD5-4493-90BD-98F94A881626/Compression%20in%20Hadoop%20%28Microsoft%20IT%20white%20paper%29.docx) for details.